# Открыть ссылку в новой вкладке на js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как открыть все ссылки в блоке `#blok_1` и `#blok_3` в новой вкладке на `js`, так чтобы не добавлять никакой код в сами ссылки ?

```css
#blok_1,
#blok_2,
#blok_3 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: #FDF5D9;
}
a {
  color: #0D6AF3;
  font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div id="blok_1">
  <a href="http://www.php.su/">открыть в новом окне</a>
</div>


<div id="blok_2">
  <a href="http://www.php.su/">открыть в текущем окне</a>
</div>


<div id="blok_3">
  <a href="http://www.php.su/">открыть в новом окне</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этих целей существуют события и функция `window.open()`. Событие соответственно на `click`. Функция `window.open(url, target, params)` принимает два параметра, урл новой страницы и 'target', это имя новой страницы, обычно для окрытия новой вкладки используют `_blank` и параметры для новой вкладки, их значения можно посмотреть на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Можно сделать это двумя способами.

Первый - создать функцию, принимающую объект DOM, в котором надо переходить по ссылкам в новом окне, придется вызвать эту функцию для каждого блока, в котором должно быть такое поведение:

```
function inNewWindow(block) {
    block.on('click', 'a:not([href^="#"])', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        window.open(evt.target.href, '_blank');
    })
}
```

1. создаем обработчик события на саму обертку (в нашем случае это будут `#blok_1` и `#blok_3`). На случай, если ссылки могут появиться внутри блока динамически. Можно повесить событие непосредственно на ссылки, дело от этого не изменится;
2. фильтровать будет только ссылки по их селектору: `a:not([href^="#"])` или `a[href^="http://"]` и `a[href^="https://"]`; хочется же, чтобы переход был именно по ссылке, а не по якорю.
3. в обработчике остановим обработку события по-умолчанию, чтобы переход внутри страницы не был совершен (надо смотреть, чтобы это не повредило общей логики работы сайта) и совершим переход с помощью `window.open()`;
4. соответственно работать с этой функцией так: `inNewWindow(document.getElementById('blok_1'))`.

Второй немного лучше, но придется дописать атрибут к элементам.

1. допишем к элементам, по которым должен быть переход на новую страницу, пучстой data-атрибут, например, `data-newwindow`;
2. выберем все элементы с таким атрибутом и повесим на них такой же обработчик, как и в первом варианте.
3. тогда придется всего лишь дописать вот это с скрипт:

```
$('[data-newwindow]').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    window.open(evt.target.href, '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Поставить слушатели на событие `click` на все интересующие нас элементы, затем смотрим что написано в аттрибуте `href`, и открываем новое окно методом `window.open`. JQuery:

```
$('div a').on('click', function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    window.open(href, '_blank').focus();
});
```

Comment: Можно добавить `event.preventDefault();` для отмены каких-либо других действий по событию.

Comment: Ссылка открывается в новой вкладке, но и страница на которой находятся ссылки, также переходит по новому адресу.

Comment: @Muson для учёта этого я и написал комментарий

Comment: Как сделать чтобы ссылки открывались в новом окне, только в блоках с id #blok_1, #blok_3

Comment: @Muson, сделать соответствующую выборку элементов: `$('#block1, #block2')`

Comment: меня интересует этот ' $('div a').on('click', function() {'  кусок кода он означает что все ссылки в блоках будут открываться в новых вкладках, так  '$('#block1, #block2').on('click', function() {' не работает.

Comment: @Muson, `$('#block1 a, #block2 a')`.

Comment: $('div a') так работает.  $('#block1 a, #block2 a')  а так нет

Comment: @Muson, css-селекторы изучайте: http://forwebdev.ru/css/how-css-selectors-work/