# Реферер (откуда пришли) на js - вопрос по ответу на stackoverflow

Tags: javascript

Нужно открыть ссылку в новой вкладке с помощью JS, так, чтобы сайт, куда переходим не мог отследить, откуда я пришёл. Нашёл такое решение:
[Открыть ссылку в новой вкладке на js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453822/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js)

Правильно ли я понимаю, что ответ юзера Fenex оттуда позволит мне сделать именно так, как я хочу, т.е. сайт, на который я перехожу таким образом не узнает источник перехода?

Comment: А взять и проверить? Не?

Comment: Сейчас начинается массовый переход на HTTPS, в котором Referrer не передается. Ваша проблема исчезнет сама собой через несколько месяцев или лет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, неправильно. Там используется обычный `window.open`, который тоже передает `Referer`.

Для того, чтобы не передавать Referer, можно использовать обычную ссылку (`<a>`) с атрибутом `rel=noreferrer`. Правда, это работает только с новыми браузерами, которые в курсе про HTML5 - старые все равно передадут `Referer`.